# Переход в другое активити

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, хочу сделать простенькое приложение для андройд на java, где нужно отвечать на вопросы в тесте, при нажатии на кнопку будет переход на новый вопрос, мне нужно будет на каждый вопрос из теста создавать новое активити, то есть если например 30 вопросов нужно будет 30 активити или можно по другому как то сделать попроще?

Comment: с активити будет слишком сложно и ресурсоемко. Я бы посмотрел в сторону фрагмента. И можно это реализовать в одном фрагменте, для экономии ресурсов

Comment: Можно (даже нужно) сделать по-другому. Просто меняйте текст в `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно всё в одной Activity: при нажатии на кнопку ("кнопку ответа" я так понял из Вашего вопроса) в TextView(например) будет обновляться вопрос, а в кнопках ответов устанавливаться новые ответы, соответствующие новому вопросу. Соответственно, нужно создать свой класс Question.class с несколькими полями: поле String самого вопроса(либо поле int, хранящее идентификатор строкового ресурса), 3-4 поля String для вариантов ответа(либо поля int, хранящие идентификаторы строковых ресурсов) и поле int(например), которое будет хранить номер правильного ответа. Далее создаем массив вопросов Question[] questions и переменную для индекса массива, которую будем увеличивать при нажатии на любой ответ, и в зависимости от которой в наше TextView и кнопки будут подгружаться необходимые строковые ресурсы. Соответственно каждой кнопке ответа устанавливается OnClickListener и в методе onClick() мы инкрементируем переменную индекса массива и вызываем методы setText для TextView и кнопок. Как-то так должно получиться, сам начинающий, не судите строго :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, сделаю как посоветовали, да это будет проще и удобнее.